# How to add dependency to ExternalProject_Add with CMake

Tags: cmake

I have an external project **license_reader**

```
ExternalProject_Add(
  license_reader
  PREFIX "${BUILD_DIR}"
  SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/license_reader"
  CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${BUILD_TYPE}
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${BUILD_DIR}
DEPENDS openssl
)
```

I want my it to link with OpenSSL when building it using CMake.

How can I pass the argument for linkage using **CMAKE_ARGS**?

Comment: `CMAKE_{EXE,SHARED}_LINKER_FLAGS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few tries, I managed to do it is adding the following line:

```
set(LICENSE_READER_LIBRARIES "${LICENSE_READER_LIBRARY};${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES};dl")
```

and overall the CMake looks like this:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
  license_reader
  PREFIX "${BUILD_DIR}"
  SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/license_reader"
  CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${BUILD_TYPE}
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${BUILD_DIR}
DEPENDS openssl
)
set(LICENSE_READER_LIBRARIES "${LICENSE_READER_LIBRARY};${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES};dl")
```